# Error al seleccionar varias filas de un JTable en Java

Tags: java, jtable, getselectedrow

Tengo un `JTable` en el cual puedo visualizar todos los datos de mis clientes.

Bien, si selecciono uno a uno (por fila) el usuario que quiero, en el `System.out.println` se ve como se muestra correctamente. El problema viene al intentar seleccionar varios, entonces si pulso Ctrl+click sobre la fila (para tener varios usuarios seleccionados para posteriores operaciones), detecta TODAS las filas seleccionadas como si fuera la primera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿A qué se debe?**

**Código:**

```
private void tabla_clientesMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
        int nFilasSelec = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRowCount(); 
        if(nFilasSelec>=0)
            button_deseleccion.setEnabled(true);
        else
            button_deseleccion.setEnabled(false);
        
        int fila = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRow();
        DefaultTableModel modelotabla = (DefaultTableModel) tabla_clientes.getModel();

        String DNI = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(fila, 0);
        String nombre = (String) modelotabla.getValueAt(fila, 1);
        String apellidos = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(fila, 2);
        String telefono = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(fila, 3);
        String direccion = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(fila, 4);
        String ciudad = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(fila, 5);
        String email = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(fila, 6);
        
        Cliente c = new Cliente(nombre, apellidos, DNI, telefono, direccion, ciudad, email);
        System.out.println(c.toString()); 
    }
```

Y si deselecciono las filas haciendo Ctrl+click sobre las filas hasta tener 0 seleccionadas, me da el siguiente error: **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si usas selección múltiple deberías usar `getSelectedRows()` (en plural). Por el contrario `getSelectedRow()` regresa sólo un índice, el primero de los seleccionados, y si no hay selección regresa `-1`, que es un índice inválido para `getValueAt()`. Deberías validar si hay selección antes extraer los datos. Y por otro lado, te ahorrarías mucho si implementaras tu propio table model para `Cliente`.

Comment: @Sal Tienes razón en todo pero no soy tan profesional (jeje). Lo acabo de realizar como usted dice getSelectedRows, pero se me muestran las filas seleccionadas, no uno a uno... es decir, primero selecciono fila1, se muestra, luego selecciono fila2 y se muestra pero con fila 1: fila1, fila1+fila2, no se muestra: fila1, fila2

Answer (score 1):

`getSelectedRow()` siempre te devuelve la primera fila seleccionada, o -1 si no hay ninguna seleccionada.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow()

> public int getSelectedRow()
> Returns the index of the first selected row, -1 if no row is selected.
> Returns:
> the index of the first selected row

Así que:

- Si usas `getSelectedRow`, debes comprobar que el valor devuelto no sea -1 (no hay fila -1)
- Si quieres listar todas las seleccionadas, puedes usar `getSelectedRows()`, que te devuelve un array con los índices de las filas.

Comment: Tu explicación del getSelectedRow -1 lo entendí por eso el error final de ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, deduzco. ¿Pero por qué me muestra en todos los System.out.println siempre el primero si selecciono diferentes filas? ¿Cómo debería solucionarlo o de esta manera no sería posible?

Comment: `getSelectedRow` no te muestra el row que ha cambiado, te muestra **el primero** de los seleccionados. Usa el método `getSelectedRows`

Comment: Entonces debo usar getSelectedRows, guardar todos los índices en un array de "filas" e ir recorriéndolos y mostrarlos en el system.outprintln uno a uno, ¿es así?

Comment: Sí, esa es la idea.

Comment: He conseguido mostrar por selecciones con getSelectedRows recorriendo el array de índices.